# "Error at Data Flow Task" in SSIS package when trying to simulate CASE expression

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I search this error and found some link for that question but I couldn't found what's my mistake 
there is my situation :

I need add a case expression to my result before transfer data with `SSIS` package

```
,CASE
        WHEN [REFERENCE]  = 33 THEN 'Planned Purchase Orders'
        WHEN [REFERENCE]  = 34 THEN 'Planned Transfer' 
   END AS [REFERENCENAME]
```

and for some reason I can't do that on source ,
however i,ve tried handle that with derived column in `SSIS` with this syntax `([REFERENCE] == "33"  ) ? "Planned Purchase Orders": ( [REFERENCE] )`
but I've got this error :

```
    TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio
------------------------------

Error at Data Flow Task [Derived Column [151]]: The data types "DT_I4" and "DT_WSTR" are incompatible for binary operator "==". The operand types could not be implicitly cast into compatible types for the operation. To perform this operation, one or both operands need to be explicitly cast with a cast operator.

Error at Data Flow Task [Derived Column [151]]: Attempt to set the result type of binary operation "REFERENCE == "33"" failed with error code 0xC0047080.

Error at Data Flow Task [Derived Column [151]]: Computing the expression "([REFERENCE] == "33"  ) ? "Planned Purchase Orders": ( [REFERENCE] )" failed with error code 0xC0047084. The expression may have errors, such as divide by zero, that cannot be detected at parse time, or there may be an out-of-memory error.

Error at Data Flow Task [Derived Column [151]]: The expression "([REFERENCE] == "33"  ) ? "Planned Purchase Orders": ( [REFERENCE] )" on "Derived Column.Outputs[Derived Column Output].Columns[Derived Column 1]" is not valid.

Error at Data Flow Task [Derived Column [151]]: Failed to set property "Expression" on "Derived Column.Outputs[Derived Column Output].Columns[Derived Column 1]".



------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0204006 (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a guess, but I assume that `Reference` is an int? If so you need to do something like this and convert the value to a WSTR in your "else":

```
([REFERENCE] == 33 ) ? "Planned Purchase Orders": ( (DT_WSTR,30) [REFERENCE] )
```

SSIS doesn't implicitly cast values; you have to be very explicit (it won't even implicitly cast a WSTR for an STR). As a result you had to specify to convert the I4 to a WSTR using the `DT_WSTR`  function.